# 2-D array Friends of Friends List

Tags: java

```
2*2 Matrix

Men  Friends
A     B,C,D
B     E,F 
C     A
E     B
F     B 
G     F
```

I need list of Friends and Friends of Friends for requested men.

Example Like G -> F,B,E,F,B and After removing duplicate F,B,E

I resolved it with loops and recursion but not satisfied

Need better approach/suggestion.. rest i will implement.

Comment: Have you tried something? Then show some code. If not, try

Comment: I tried with loops and Also got solution but not satisfied.
Need some better approach except simple iteration

Comment: Posting some code not only shows effort, but also gives some context to your request. Without that, your requirements are difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like this. Of course, i have taken a bit of freedom on the design as you didnt provide any code. Hope this helps!

```
private static Set<Node> getNodesFollowAllEdges(Node node) {
    Set<Node> nodes = getNodesFollowAllEdges(node, new HashSet<>());
    // remember to remove the original node from the set
    nodes.remove(node);
    return nodes;
}

private static Set<Node> getNodesFollowAllEdges(Node node, Set<Node> visited) {
    if (node.getConnectedNodes().isEmpty()) {
        return visited;
    }

    for (Node n : node.getConnectedNodes()) {
        if (!visited.contains(n)) {
            visited.add(n);
            getNodesFollowAllEdges(n, visited);
        }
    }
    return visited;
}
```

Also, it is very easy to provide a maximum search dept. Just add `int maxDept` and increase it every recursion step.

Given the following example:

```
Node a = new Node("A");
Node b = new Node("B");
Node c = new Node("C");
Node d = new Node("D");
Node e = new Node("E");
Node f = new Node("F");
Node g = new Node("G");

a.addConnectedNodes(b, c, d);
b.addConnectedNodes(e, f);
c.addConnectedNodes(a);
e.addConnectedNodes(b);
f.addConnectedNodes(b);
g.addConnectedNodes(f);

Set<Node> friends = getNodesFollowAllEdges(a);
friends.forEach(node -> System.out.println(node.getName()));
```

should give you the correct result of (order neglected)

```
B
F
E
```

Note: Remember that, since its a `Set`, the resulting nodes can be in any order.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Glains,

My Code is :

```
public class Demo {

    Set<String> freinds = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] emailArray = new String[][] {
                { "abc@gmail.com", "abc1@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com,abc3@gmail.com,1212@gmail.com" },
                { "abc1@gmail.com", "bcs1@gmail.combc2@gmail.com,bcds3@gmail.com" },
                { "bc@gmail.com", "bc1@gmail.combc2@gmail.com,bc3@gmail.com" } };

        new Demo().sendMail("@gmail.combc2@gmail.com", "sdsd", emailArray);

    }

    void sendMail(String email, String message, String[][] freindsArray) {
        Map<String, Email> emailsMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < freindsArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                Email e = new Email(freindsArray[i][j]);
                e.addConnectedNodes(freindsArray[i][j + 1]);
                emailsMap.put(e.email, e);
            }
        }
        if (emailsMap.containsKey(email)) {
            Demo.getNodesFollowAllEdges(emailsMap.get(email), emailsMap).forEach(e -> {
                System.out.println(e);
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("no emails exist");
        }


    }

    private static Set<String> getNodesFollowAllEdges(Email e, Map<String, Email> emailsMap) {
        Set<String> nodes = getNodesFollowAllEdges(e, new HashSet<>(), emailsMap);
        nodes.remove(e.email);
        return nodes;
    }

    private static Set<String> getNodesFollowAllEdges(Email node, Set<String> visited, Map<String, Email> emailsMap) {

        if (node.getConnectedEmails().isEmpty()) {
            return visited;
        }

        for (String n : node.getConnectedEmails()) {
            if (!visited.contains(n)) {
                visited.add(n);
                if (emailsMap.get(n) != null) {
                    getNodesFollowAllEdges(emailsMap.get(n), visited, emailsMap);
                }
            }
        }
        return visited;
    }

}

class Email {
    String email;
    List<String> freindsEmails = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getConnectedEmails() {
        return freindsEmails;
    }

    public Email(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void addConnectedNodes(String friendsEmail) {
        freindsEmails.addAll(Arrays.asList(friendsEmail.split(",")));
    }

}
```